# How to display motd or banner when users ssh directly into screen session

Tags: display, unix

I have several users that connect to the same service account but under different screen sessions. So they would use a command such as:

`ssh -t user@myserver screen -Dr specificSessionName`

I would like a banner message or motd message to display every time this connection happens.

Comment: add that banner message to '/etc/motd'   and or  specify a banner path in your .ssh/ssh_config for that host server

Comment: @linuxdev2013: It is in /etc/motd but the problem is if the session is already running, it doesn't display again. If I login with no screen it shows just fine.

Answer (score 0):

By this ssh command, screen is triggered **immediately** right after authentication is done, it's is told to reattach its session with its output abandoned before, it does so, so there is no place for ssh to show motd.

But if you insist on that and you are alert, you can rename screen to something like screen.bin and write a wrapper script with its original name. That script would be responsible for printing /etc/motd and after some sleep and/or getting user input, it could go on to startd screen with the session name it got in its parameter.

Pretty dirty and you better watch in case upgrade comes to your screen package.

Comment: Hm --- is there a way to change the screen command to show it? I'm hoping to not write a wrapper....

Comment: Well... yes... there's an option for another dirty solution: with the echo command of screen you can display any message. The problem is that it's displayed before screen show the session's output, and we know that it does that very quickly. So if you wish the msg to be readable, you must use sleep right after echo. Ah, and echo uses literal string, so the content of /etc/motd must be literally copied there.

Comment: what shell is being used on the server side? There is a possibility that you could run the tty  with some on_start style scripts which would among other things  'echo /etc/motd'  or printf '/etc/motd'